# get object from array by index

Tags: mongodb

how can I get an object of array by index

**example:**

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "bob", colors: [ "red", "blue", "green"] }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "jim", colors: ["yellow", "black" ] }
```

my query: something like

`db.users.find({name: "bob"},  {colors: 2})`

**result**:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "bob", colors: "blue" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name": "bob" }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "color": { "$slice": [ "$colors", 1, 1 ] }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$color" }
])
```

Above query will  return

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "name": "bob"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$arrayElemAt` to get the n-th item in array:

```
db.users.aggregate([
      {$match: {name: "bob"}},
      {$project: {name: "$name", color: {$arrayElemAt: ['$colors', 1]}}}
])
```

Note that the index is 0-based.